# Estimating query impact in MongoDB Atlas Data Lake

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, atlas-data-lake

Is there a way to estimate cost/amount of data read by the query without actually running it?

Similar to Google's Big Query `--dry_run` flag

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is such a feature at the moment. However, you can run `explain()` on the query, e.g. `db.airbnb.explain().find(....)`. The query plan should show you the node `url` which contains the size, e.g.:

```
> db.airbnb.explain().find({ "address.market" : "New York", "price": {$lt: NumberDecimal("200.00")} } )
{
  "ok" : 1,
  "plan" : {
    "kind" : "multiPlanNode",
    "regionPlans" : {
      "2/ap-southeast-2" : {
....
        "node" : {
          "kind" : "data",
          "partitions" : [
            {
              "url" : "s3://xxxx/json/airbnb/listingsAndReviews.json?agentRegion=2%2Fap-southeast-2&format=.json&region=ap-southeast-2&size=92.65681457519531+MiB",
              "attributes" : {

              }
            }
....
```

Note the section:

`"url" : "s3://xxxx/json/airbnb/listingsAndReviews.json?agentRegion=2%2Fap-southeast-2&format=.json&region=ap-southeast-2&size=92.65681457519531+MiB"`

means that the query will read that S3 URL, which is 92 MB in size.

**Edit**: As pointed to by @willis, running `explain()` without any parameter will **not** actually run the query, but will only display the execution plan (see [explain() behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#behavior)). However, with `explain('executionStats')`, the query will actually be executed.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify - `explain().find()` would not actually *run* the query. It would just show what the plan. Correct?

Comment: That's correct. It will only run the query if you pass something like `{executionStatus: true}` otherwise it will just figure out the query plan  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/